# Couldn't read stream from external process

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

Following is my program which I wrote in order to start a process in linux and print the result in console.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Process process = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/R").start();
            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting that the R version and other stuff which will be displayed when I start R in terminal, to be printed in the console. But nothing gets printed and there is no exception.

What is the issue here?

EDIT

My program above works when I use a command like "ls" or "ps". but not for any command which doesn't exit by its own

Comment: first, when you launch the process by java, is it viewable by the on top command line on *unix, or process explorer under Windows ?

Comment: should it be still listed in top even after my java program exits?

Comment: Try closing the process output stream before you start reading.

Comment: i did  process.getOutputStream().close(); just before the while loop. didn't help

Comment: My program above works when I use a command like "ls" or "ps". but not for any command which doesn't exit by its own

Comment: Tried "./usr/bin/R" ?

Answer (score 2):

As the process is started in a separate thread, `br` may just have wrong state when execution reaches the loop.

Primitive solution: if you do not need to interact with started process, you can add `process.waitFor()` before the loop to make sure the process has finished and output is available.

In general, interaction with external process will require separate threads to monitor its state, read std out and std err streams. In this case, it makes sense to use a library solution, e.g. [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) (see [the tutorial](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html))

Comment: I used the sample program form commons and it works only with commands which exits by its own. I need to read from a process which doesn't exit by its own. is there a way to do it in commons

Comment: I am not sure what is the new code, but try using `PumpStreamHandler`  and  asynchronious form of exec: `Executor.execute(CommandLine command, ExecuteResultHandler handler)`